# How do I remove spaces around each field in a CSV in Perl?

Tags: csv, perl

My CSV files with whitespace:

```
Id ;   FirstName   ;   LastName  ;    email
123;    Marc       ;   TOTO      ;    marc@toto.com
```

I would like delete whitespace  in my csv by line like this :

```
Id;FirstName;LastName;email
123;Marc;TOTO;marc@toto.com
```

I would use a regex in Perl.

Comment: look for a trim regex or `chomp($line)`

Answer (score 4):

It is always a good idea to use a library with file formats like CSV.  Even as this case seems trivial and safe to parse with regex surprises can and do sneak up. Also, requirements tend to change and projects and data only get more complex. Once there is sensible code using a good library a project evolution is generally far more easily absorbed.

A library like the excellent [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) can use `;` as a separator and can remove that extra whitespace while parsing the file, with a suitable option.

To keep it short and in a one-liner the [functional interface](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#FUNCTIONS) is helpful

```
perl -MText::CSV=csv -we' 
    csv (in => *ARGV, sep => ";", allow_whitespace => 1)' name.csv > new.csv
```

Prints as desired with the supplied example file.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perl solution but the awk solution is so simple it might be acceptable:

```
awk '{OFS="";$1=$1;print $0}' file.csv;
```

This process uses `OFS` to override the default output field separator from the usual white space. $1=$1 forces awk to reset the whole line $0 value to remove the field separators before printing it.

Comment: You should probably include that this may break csv data and should only be used with a small, well-defined set of csv.

Comment: It removes white space, If your desired output needs spaces, obviously don't use it. The original file remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Although your title says `remove spaces at the end of each line`, you may
want to remove whitespaces around the field values. Then would you please try:

```
perl -pe "s/\s*;\s*/;/g" input_file.csv
```

Output:

```
Id;FirstName;LastName;email
123;Marc;TOTO;marc@toto.com
```

Please note the code breaks in case the field contains `;` itself such as `abc;"foo ; bar";def` or other complicated cases.

Comment: You should probably include that this may break csv data and should only be used with a small, well-defined set of csv.

Comment: @TLP thank you for the suggestion. I should have included the limitations in my answer. BR.